# Asp.net core 3.1 AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I stumbled on this error on my mapping with automapper. I'll first explain my use case

I have created a website where it has a referral feature,I am using select2 js for dropdown with search functionality BTW, and have a API that will return Id and fullname for the selection of who the person put you on their referral, because the only one can put the referral is only with the administrator account, so this is the model for all the users

```
public partial class AspNetUsers
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedFullname { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Referral { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public bool? Suspended { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to map it to this viewmodel

```
public class ReferralViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

and on my mapping profile I use this code

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AspNetUsers, ProfileViewModel>();

        CreateMap<AspNetUsers, ReferralViewModel>();
    }
}
```

and on my startup file I added this configuration

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
   mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
 });
 IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
 services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

and on my code to get the users I use this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchUser(string term)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
        {
            var users = await _context.AspNetUsers.Where(a => a.Fullname != null).Where(a => a.Fullname.Contains(term)).ToListAsync();
           
            var mappedUser = _mapper.Map<ReferralViewModel>(users);
            return Ok(mappedUser);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

but when I call the method to get the mapped user. it returns error like this

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
> Object -> ReferralViewModel
> System.Object -> Genea.Areas.Admin.Models.ReferralViewModel lambda_method(Closure , object , ReferralViewModel , ResolutionContext)
> lambda_method(Closure , object , ReferralViewModel , ResolutionContext)
> AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
> AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
> AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(object source)
> Genea.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProfileController.SearchUser(string term) in ProfileController.cs +
> var mappedUser = _mapper.Map(users);

I don't why that error happened

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

You have defined/configured a map from the `AspNetUsers` to  `ReferralViewModel`, but you are trying to map a list of `AspNetUsers` to a single `ReferralViewModel` object.

Modify your mapping to -

```
var mappedUser = _mapper.Map<List<ReferralViewModel>>(users);
```

That should solve your issue.

**Not related to your issue :**

1. You can simplify the registration of `AutoMapper` with only -

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

if the `Startup` class and the `MappingProfile` class are in the same assembly/project. If they are not, then with -

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));
```

In either case, you don't need the following codes -

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
   mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
 });
 IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
 services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

(I'm assuming that you already have the `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` package installed.)

2. You can simplify your query code as -

```
var users = await _context.AspNetUsers
    .Where(a => a.Fullname != null && a.Fullname.Contains(term))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thanks, I already resolve the issue yesterday not it works

Comment: out of the top,  but  what if I will return a single user, what will I do?

Comment: @WinDel In that case you would query for a single user, and map it to a single `ReferralViewModel` instance.

Comment: Appreciate you much @atiyar